# Loop through array and join in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, join, google-sheets

I have an array (res_1) in the below format

```
[[ABC, 42341.82000000001, 100.0, US], [DEF, 80114.36, 100.0, US]]
```

There is a sheet called "Details" that I read using

```
var sd=ss.getSheetByName('Details');
var sdvs=sd.getDataRange().getValues();
```

[image]

I need to loop through the array res_1 and if the first element is "ABC", then refer to the field "ID" in "Details" table and get corresponding "First%" and "Second%" fields. Those fields need to be appended to res_1 array.

Not sure whether there could be a join condition to achieve this. Any suggestions/leads would be appreciated.

Hence, the result need to be

```
[[ABC, 12341, 12.20, 7.40, 100.0, US], [DEF, 11134.36, 21.00, 7.00, 100.0, US]]
```

Comment: Sorry but google apps script doesn't work in excel.  And this array is incorrect `[[ABC, 42341.82000000001, 100.0, US], [DEF, 80114.36, 100.0, US]]` because the strings are not quoted.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow please take this opportunity to take the [tour] and learn how to [ask], [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks), [mcve] and [Learn More](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info)

Comment: Please show what you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot understand about the logic that the values of `42341.82000000001` and `80114.36` in `res_1` are removed at the output result you expect. And also, I cannot understand about the logic for adding the values of `12341` and `11134.36` at the output result. I apologize for this. Can I ask you about the detail logic for retrieving your expected value? And, in your output value, for example, `0` is added like `12.20`. In this case, you want to use this as the string?

Comment: To add to Tanaike's comment, your questions asks how to append the values from the First% and Second% columns.   However, your expected output has the values in a certain order.  Does the order matter?  Why did the second value change?  Are the appended values suppose to stay percentages, or will you reconvert them to percentages at another place?  Lastly, if the order of the values is important, it might be better loop through and create an object so you can access specific values more easily.